# How to Check if a Child Category is Being Queried

Tags: categories, wp-query, query

I need to change the number of posts queried for specific categories 'Recipes' or 'Product Reviews'.  The below code works great for this, I have it in functions.php:

```
function change_number_of_posts($query) {
    if ($query->is_category && ( $query->is_category('recipes') || $query->is_category('product-reviews') ) )
    $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = -1; // Show all posts
    return $query; // Return our modified query variables
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_number_of_posts'); // Hook our custom function onto the request filter
```

The problem is that the 'Product Reviews' category is a parent category, so the above code does not work when one of its child categories is being queried.

I can use the `'cat_is_ancestor_of()'` function in my loop to do what I need to with these subcategories, but I cannot get it to work in functions.php and am thinking it cannot be called from there.

I basically want to say
"If the category is 'recipes' or 'product-reviews' or a child of 'product-reviews'..." from my functions.php file.

I know I can hard code all the subcategories, but I don't want to have to edit the php every time I add a subcategory of Product Reviews.

I have spent hours trying to find a solution, any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You *should* be able to use `cat_is_ancestor_of` in your `functions.php`, in particular in your `change_number_of_posts` function. Could you post some code to show how you are using it?

Comment: That is great that cat_is_ancestor_of can be used.  I guess then I don't know which argument to pass for the second variable.  

    'code'
if ($query->is_category('recipes') || $query->is_category('product-reviews') || cat_is_ancestor_of(6,WHAT-GOES-HERE?)
'code'

Thanks! (so sorry, I don't know how to format this properly!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`cat_is_ancestor_of`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/cat_is_ancestor_of) takes two arguments (two category IDs). To check if category of ID 61 is ancestor of category with 54:

```
 cat_is_ancestor_of(54,61);
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this, but you can get the current category's ID with the [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) and then check this an ancestor of the category with some ID (6 in this example):.

```
function change_number_of_posts($query) {
    if ($query->is_category){
         $cat = get_queried_object();
         $cat_id = (int) $cat->term_id;

         if( $query->is_category('recipes') || $query->is_category('product-reviews')){
              $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = -1; 
         }elseif(cat_is_ancestor_of(6,$cat_id)){
              $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = -1; 
         }
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_number_of_posts');
```

*Untested*.

(I've left out any checking of errors (e.g. in case the category doesn't exist)).

Comment: That's it!!  I did not know how to extract the Category ID of the current query as an int.  Thank you so very much.  :)