# Change post order by meta key, per post basis

Tags: loop, pre-get-posts

I have a loop definition like this in `functions.php`:

```
function artist_list($query) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    // Target the artists page
    if (is_tax('artist-category')) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '-1');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        $query->set('meta_key', 'artist_last_name');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'artist_list');
```

I'm listing artists from taxonomy and alphabetising them according their last name. But on some occasions the artists should be alphabetised by the first name, and this should be controlled inside each post from the back end.

I need info from the post before the loop starts, and I can only get it in the loop.

I'm gonna make a checkbox in the backend where the user can choose how to  alphabetise. Roughly like this:

[image]

How should I do this? Is the `pre_get_posts` the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to make `WP_Query`, or `SQL`, do this. In the backend, don't save `artist_last_name` save something like `artist_sort_name` instead, and set it to either first or last name accordingly, then sort on that normalized key.

To sort conditionally with `WP_Query`-- that is, to ignore my advise above and try to make `WP_Query`/`SQL` do this-- you would need to write a filter and some relatively complicated `SQL` that would not likely be very efficient-- that is, it would likely execute slowly.

See the following for a similar question/answer:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134001/21376

Answer (score 1):

For future generations, here's what I ended up doing.

Use `artist_sort_name` for sorting and just change the value in that field to `artist_first_name` or `artist_last_name` (thanks to s_ha_dums answer).

I'm using [WPAlchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) class to make the metaboxes and custom fields. I had to call the [`save_filter`](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#options) to run a function before the save (this is in `functions.php` file):

```
// Save filter function, check the value of alphabetize custom field
// if it's set then use first name as sort name
function nd_meta_sort($meta, $post_id) {
    if ($meta['alphabetize'] == "alphabetize") {
        $meta['artist_sort_name'] = $meta['artist_first_name'];
    } else {
        $meta['artist_sort_name'] = $meta['artist_last_name'];
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

And here's how the metabox is defined in `functions.php`:

```
// Metabox for artists
$custom_metabox_artist = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array(
    'id'                 => 'artist_custom_meta',
    'title'              => 'Artist Info',
    'template'           => TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/meta-artists.php',
    'types'              => array('artists'),
    'mode'               => WPALCHEMY_MODE_EXTRACT,
    'hide_screen_option' => TRUE,
    'save_filter'        => 'nd_meta_sort' // This get executed when saving the post
));
```

And here's the actual metabox:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label>First Name:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <!-- Field for the first name -->
                <?php $mb->the_field('artist_first_name'); ?>
                <input name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" class="artist-name" type="text" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>">
                <!-- Checkbox for for choosing which field to sort -->
                <span>
                    <?php $mb->the_field('alphabetize'); ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="alphabetize" <?php $mb->the_checkbox_state('alphabetize'); ?>>
                    Alphabetize First Name
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label>Lastname:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <!-- Field for the last name -->
                <?php $mb->the_field('artist_last_name'); ?>
                <input name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" class="artist-name" type="text" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- The field the post are sorted to. Note that it's hidden -->
<?php $mb->the_field('artist_sort_name'); ?>
<input name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" class="artist-name sort-name" type="hidden" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>">
```

The `table` is no means mandatory there, it's just how label/field pares are usually displayed in WP backend.

It looks something like this:

[image]

And sake of completeness here's the loop that gets the artists. I'm using the `pre_get_posts` in `functions.php`:

```
function artist_list($query) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    // Target the artists page
    if (is_tax('artist-category')) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '-1');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        $query->set('meta_key', "artist_sort_name");
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'artist_list');
```